# Android: Correctly downloading/saving an email attachement

Tags: android, email, download, save, attachment

I have an interesting problem: My application is designed to send and open up a zip full of files, and the zip has a special extension (easier for the user). I can zip up the files I need to attach in an e-mail, and I can send them.

When I use the g-mail "view" button and select my app to open the file, it doesn't unzip them correctly. However, if I use the gmail "download" button, and then open the file through a file explorer, the file unzips correctly.

This is the code I use to download the attachment:

```
// get attachment
        try {
            attachment = getContentResolver().openInputStream(
                    getIntent().getData());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // Save it
        try {
            File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            path = root.getPath() + "/PSattachment.psz";
            savedFile = new File(path);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(savedFile, false);
            BufferedOutputStream os = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int byteRead = 0;
            while ((byteRead = attachment.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                os.write(buffer, 0, byteRead);
            }
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance. (Also, the process of unzipping is the same in both cases [file explorer and view from email], so I'm pretty sure it's something in here. Also, the file DOES download, and is the right size. It just won't unzip).

Comment: try using OutputStreamWriter instead of the BufferedOutputStream

Comment: just try changing os from BufferedOutputStream  to OutputStreamWriter .. os.write(buffer,0,byteRead) will still work

Comment: oh you are right ): .. anyway i thought that maybe it is the problem because i used it instead after many trials

Comment: Ok, thanks anyways for trying.

Comment: Is there a way to use the download method from the gmail app?

Comment: if it is open source (which i doubt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer!!! Took a while, but at least it works now:

```
            try {
            InputStream attachment = getContentResolver()
                    .openInputStream(getIntent().getData());
            savedFile = new File(Environment
                    .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),
                    "temp" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".psz");
            FileOutputStream f = new FileOutputStream(savedFile);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len1 = 0;
            while ((len1 = attachment.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                f.write(buffer);
            }
            f.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
```

I just used this code to download the attachment and now everything works perfectly =D

Answer (score 0):

Check this out please: 
[http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_(Programmatically)](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Unzipping_Files_with_Android_%28Programmatically%29)

A guide to unzip files in android, hope it helps solve your problem

Comment: 2. The unzipping part works fine. It's that the file being saved isn't being saved right.